# Testing Forms in Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I need to write a test for a web service that makes a request like the following:

`curl -X POST -v -F 'id=1234' -F 'name=blah.png' -F 'contentType=image/png' -F 'file=@somefile.png' path/to/some/endpoint`

The documentation: [robot request documentation](https://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/)
, doesn't suggest that it has a method to mock forms.  I'm I missing something or do I need to write some python code outside of the robot request library to make a request like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it is an HTML form, my first instinct is that this should be implemented using the Robot Framework [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html) which performs browser automation.

However, if you do not have access to the actual application performing this request or the request is not sent by a browser HTML form, then using the `Post` keyword from the [RequestsLibrary](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/#Post) is the approach to take. It will create a request like the `curl` example from question. However, as Robot Framework is a script DSL, there won't be a Form UI to play with.

Comment: Hi A.Kootstra!  Do you know how to mock the -F (or form) flag using robot's post request?

Comment: After a bit more research, looks like the robot requests lib should handle a multipart form see: https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/issues/131.  Going to accept this answer. Thanks!